# How to set Reply-To for all emails sent to a distribution group on Office 365?

Tags: office365, exchange-2013

I'm using Office 365 E3 and I have a distribution group used for a mailing list including people inside our organisation and contacts outside too. I have a mail transport rule set up to prefix the subject like `[My Group]` and add a 'disclaimer' to the bottom of the emails explaining why they're getting it and how to remove themselves. I'd also like to set the 'Reply-To' of all messages sent to the group so replies will by default go to the group instead of to the individual who sent the original email.

I've tried using a mail transport rule to set the `Reply-To` header but no luck: I get an error saying "You can't set header 'Reply-To' with value 'test-group@ourfirm.com'".

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure whether this will work but you might need  to re-write mail headers matching the scenarios but you would require an edge server to do so. Because, in my theoretical view the reply-to is defined by the original sender and the header is written based on the sender, at least I believe so. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you could just tweak what you are already doing:

1. Modify what you are already doing to inject some sort of marker into
   the body or subject (or just reuse the [my group] tag)
2. Create a new rule that checks for these markers and maybe a "RE:" pre-fix, and have those forwarded to intended address.

There are some cons with that approach as some messages you may not want to route could get caught up in that rule, but if you get your exclusions right that should work.

The other methods use Outlook and modify the message before it hits Exchange.

1. When crafting the message, use the advanced options and just change
   the reply-to.
2. Use a custom form and pre-set the reply-to

For #2 enable the Developer option in the Ribbon.  Then select Developer tab and create a new form for type message.  You can add the "have replies sent to" property to the message sheet then save the form.  You can use this form to create your messages just like a normal form, but the reply-to will already be sent.  If you save the .oft (form file) to a share you can allow other users to import and use it in Outlook as well.